# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, react-native, nodemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2VJJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiF0f.png)

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the Code where you import the db in your index file?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld1qG.png

Comment: When you ask questions try to actually put the code in instead of giving us screenshots of your code.,

Comment: сode takes up a lot of space

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your Imports are not handled correctly. Please take a look into the sequelize Docs to verify that you have installed and imported everything accordingly. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html

I feel like you cant just require(/db) - or is your sequelize set up in a different file?

The Error tells you that it cant find the Module /db so the import has to be wrong.

Comment: But why crashed nodemon?

Comment: about db nodemon crashed and before its creation, I thought that everything would be fixed if I run it together with the database, but I was wrong

Comment: nodemon crashes because it cant run your setup. Either your import is wrong or the way you setup sequelize. I cant tell you because I dont know your folder structure or the code you used for the db.